# How is $\Phi^{\vdash}_{PA} \subset Th(R)$?

Tags: number-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I have intuitively hard time understanding the result in mathematical logic that:

$\Phi^{\vdash}_{PA} \subset Th(R)$

$R$ here is $\{\mathbb N,+,*,0,1\}$, or in other words the standard model of natural numbers. The RH symbol means the theory of $R$ that is, the set of all provable sentences from $R$. The LH symbol is the set of all provable sentences from Peano Axioms. And Peano Axioms are formulated in terms of: $\{+,*,0,1\}$.

It's easy to see that all axioms of PA are derivable from $R$, so clearly $\Phi^{\vdash}_{PA} \subseteq Th(R) $. But once these formulas are derived from $R$, what even is the difference between the two at that point? They look exactly the same to me.

With the Beta-function lemma it can be proved that solving $Th(R)$ is equivalent to solving halting problem, so the set is not decidable and numerable, while the other set is. But it's still difficult to see what's the difference between the two. Perhaps someone can provide an intuitive example?

(I believe an equivalent proof would be that $Th(R)$ is complete, while $\Phi^{\vdash}_{PA}$ is not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there's a misunderstanding here. "$\Phi_{PA}^\vdash$," I believe, is the set of sentences provable from PA, while $Th(R)$ is the set of sentences true in the structure $R$, contrary two what you've written (incidentally, using "$R$" to denote the structure $(\mathbb{N}; +, *, 0, 1)$  is terrible). It looks like you've swapped the RHS and LHS in your explanation of what they mean.

So the statement you're trying to prove is:

- Every sentence that PA proves, is true in $R$.
- But there is a sentence true in $R$ which PA doesn't prove.

As you've observed the first is immediate, so all the weight is on the second.

At this point it's useful to point out the difference between *provability from a theory* and *truth in a structure* (in particular, phrases like "provable sentences from  $R$," "formulas are derived from $R$" treat $R$ like a theory, which it's not). If $\varphi$ is provable from a theory $T$, then there is a **witness** to this, namely a proof. In particular, the set of sentences provable from any (recursive) theory $T$ is recursively enumerable.

By contrast, there is no reason for the set of sentences true in a structure to be recursively enumerable! Roughly, the "reason" that a sentence is true in a structure may not be "finitely describable" in any way. (And when you write "With the Beta-function lemma it can be proved that solving $Th(R)$ is equivalent to solving halting problem," this is incorrect - while it is true that the halting problem can determine whether a recursive theory proves a sentence, since $Th(R)$ isn't recursively axiomatizable that doesn't help us at all.)

In fact, this is the case here: the set $Th(R)$ of all sentences true of $R$ is not recursively enumerable, hence cannot be equal to $\Phi_{PA}^{\vdash}$, which is recursively enumerable; and so this, together with the first bullet point, proves the second.

So now you just need to show that $Th(R)$ is not recursively enumerable. This is a good exercise - try to, for instance, explicitly code the set $0''$ into $Th(R)$. You'll show in this way that $Th(R)$ computes $0''$, and hence cannot be recursively enumerable.

Comment: So what exactly is $Th(R)$? Does it have anything to do with first order logic at all?

Comment: @Dole As I said in the second sentence of my answer, $Th(R)$ is the set of sentences true in the structure $R$. It is a set of first-order sentences, just like PA or $\Phi_{PA}^\vdash$; unlike those two, it is complete and is not recursively axiomatizable. To any structure $\mathcal{A}$ we associate the set  $Th(\mathcal{A})$ of sentences true in $\mathcal{A}$; that is, $$Th(\mathcal{A})=\{\varphi: \mathcal{A}\models\varphi\}.$$

Comment: @Dole That formulation makes it sound like PA comes first, and then $Th(R)$ is built on top of PA. Rather, I'd say (being a bit Platonistic for now) that $Th(R)$ is the "natural" object, being the whole theory of a structure ($R$, the natural numbers) that we care about, and PA is a reasonable *approximation* to $Th(R)$ which turns out not to be perfect (in that its deductive closure isn't all of $Th(R)$), by Goedel's theorem. In particular, there are approximations to $Th(R)$ other than PA; PA is just one of many, and so singling it out is a bit missing the picture. (cont'd)

Comment: However, **second-order** PA is a quite different story! As you probably know, second-order PA is **categorical**: $R$ is its unique model (up to isomorphism). This is actually *better* than $Th(R)$, which - being a collection of first-order sentences - can never pin down an infinite structure up to isomorphism, by the [compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem). (And in fact by compactness it's not even $\aleph_0$-categorical.) Note that Goedel's theorems (and most theorems about first-order logic) absolutely do not apply to second-order theories. (cont'd)

Comment: As soon as we talk about non-first-order logics, by the way, there's a natural generalization to make - given a structure $\mathcal{A}$ *and a logic $\mathcal{L}$*, we let $Th_\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{A})$ be the set of all $\mathcal{L}$-sentences true in $\mathcal{A}$. If we take $\mathcal{L}$ to be first-order logic, this is just $Th(\mathcal{A})$ in the usual sense. Then the point is that second-order PA is semantically equivalent to the full second-order theory of $R$. PA is a bad approximation of $Th(R)$, which is itself a bad approximation to $Th_2(R)$, which is morally equivalent to $PA_2$.

Comment: Schewber Thank you very much, fantastic answer! Just one more quick question, how can one say whether a particular sentence belongs in TH(R) or not? So if I were to extend PA or some other approximation, how can I tell whether it proves only sentences that are true in the standard model?

Comment: @Dole You can't, really. There will always be things about the natural numbers we don't know - since the theory is noncomputable (in fact, much worse than that!), any "process" we have for generating new axioms will either generate *incorrect* axioms, or will not decide every sentence.